# what happens to schedule in laravel when it is artisan down?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Is schedule still run when app in laravel is in maintenance mode?

So I put app in down:

```
php artisan down
```

and schedule in console/kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $schedule->command('tbcpay:closeday')
             ->daily() // midnight
             ->sendOutputTo('storage/logs/TbcpayCloseDay.log');

}
```

Comment: Scheduler jobs can still run while your application is in maintenance mode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821095/laravel-5-maintenance-mode-turn-on-without-artisan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop schedule when maintenance mode,you can try like that

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   if(!\App::isDownForMaintenance()){
      $schedule->command('tbcpay:closeday')
         ->daily() // midnight
         ->sendOutputTo('storage/logs/TbcpayCloseDay.log');
      }
 }
```

Comment: This is no longer the case: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#maintenance-mode

Answer (score 5):

This is not the case, the Laravel Docs confirm that the scheduler does not run in maintenance mode:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#maintenance-mode

> **Maintenance Mode**
>
> Laravel's scheduled tasks will not run when Laravel is in maintenance mode, since we don't want your tasks to interfere with any unfinished maintenance you may be performing on your server.