# Laravel 5 maintenance mode turn on without artisan

Tags: laravel

Is there any possibility to turn on and turn off Laravel 5 maintenance without php artisan up and down commands when my website is being hosted ?

What I've done:

```
Route::get('site/shutdown', function(){
    return Artisan::call('down');
});

Route::get('site/live', function(){
    return Artisan::call('up');
});
```

The first route is working fine. But when I call site/live the site still is shuted down. What can cause this problem ?

Comment: have you looked into [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling)?

Comment: check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047573/maintenance-mode-without-using-artisan

Comment: Just create a file called `down` in `storage/framework`. Tested with Laravel 5.1.

Comment: I've have updated my post

Comment: I've written answer on similar question (linked above), see my answer it solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/38836871/1564365

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If your project is already down, you cannot call another function.

What happens after you run `php artisan down` is that it creates a file named `down` inside `storage/framework`. After running `php artisan up` the file is  removed.

You can create the file manually inside `storage/framework`. It will down your project. When you want to take your project live again, just remove the file.

Comment: Can this be done with route ? I means the route which deletes the file  ?

Answer (score 6):

I think the right answer is missing here..
You could add your route to app/http/middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php

```
protected $except = [
        //here
];
```

So It never would be off.

Answer (score 5):

when you run artisan down. site is not available so when try to call up, your IP can't access site.
you must call down with your IP exception.

```
php artisan down --allow=127.0.0.1 --allow=192.168.0.0/16
```

or add ::1 to local.

to make that in route without command
try to save this command in specific one and call it.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 8 introduced `secret` in maintenance mode, in which you can bypass the maintenance mode by providing a secret, then your `Artisan::call` would work.

You could add your routes to the `$except` var in `CheckForMaintenanceMode` middleware to bypass the check. Then your `site/live` route would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your site live again using an url, you can create a live.php file which you put in laravel's public folder and then visit http://your.domain/live.php .

In the live.php file you need something like this: (check your projects directory structure if you don't use the default public folder!)

```
<?php
unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../storage/framework/down");
header("Location: your.domain"); 
die;
```

Answer (score 1):

just put

```
Artisan::call('up');
```

without route function.

Answer (score 0):

**`You cannot call another function if your project is already down.`**

> After you run **php artisan down**, it creates a file named **down**
> inside **storage/framework**.
>
> After running the **php artisan up** command the file is removed.

You can create the file manually inside the **storage/framework**. It will down your project. When you want to take your project live again, just remove the file.